# StreamTokenizer expected end character

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a tokenizer to parse mathematical input strings into their separate parts and I'm getting what seems like a trivial error in the second line of code as I post it that it's expecting an ; somewhere midway through the line.

```
public static void parseFormula(String text){
    List<String> tokenize(String s) throws IOException {
          StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
          tokenizer.ordinaryChar('-'); 
          List<String> tokBuf = new ArrayList<String>();
          while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            switch(tokenizer.ttype) {
              case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                tokBuf.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
                break;
              case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                tokBuf.add(tokenizer.sval);
                break;
              default: 
                tokBuf.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
            }
          }
          return tokBuf; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a method `tokenize` nested in `parseFormula`. Java does not allow nested methods. That is the reason for compilation error. After taking the methods apart, the following compiles ok:

```
List<String> tokenize(String s) throws IOException {
    StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar('-'); 
    List<String> tokBuf = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
      switch(tokenizer.ttype) {
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
          tokBuf.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
          break;
        case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
          tokBuf.add(tokenizer.sval);
          break;
        default: 
          tokBuf.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
      }
    }
    return tokBuf; 
  }

public static void parseFormula(String text){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
List<String> tokenize = new ArrayList<String>(s);

      StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
      tokenizer.ordinaryChar('-'); 
      List<String> tokBuf = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        switch(tokenizer.ttype) {
          case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
            tokBuf.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
            break;
          case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
            tokBuf.add(tokenizer.sval);
            break;
          default: 
            tokBuf.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
        }
      }


}catch (IOException e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

If I am not mistaken